# My discord.js code runs into problems while trying to change status

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I made a bot with botghost.com, because I thought it would be nice to have their default commands. I then overrided this bot with some python code, to have additionnal commands. But then I noticed that my bot had the BotGhost status. I tried to change it using my python script by adding this at the beggining of my code :

```
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user.name}')
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="vos commandes"), status=discord.Status.dnd)
```

It showed my description for a second, then went back to BotGhost's.

I then watched a video that supposedly fixed the problem, so I ended up with this code :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const mySecret = process.env['TOKEN']

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setActivity("Custom Status")
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('pong!');
  }
});
client.login(mySecret);
```

But then, instead of normally changing the status, it throwed me this error :

```
TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (/home/runner/testnostatus/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:509:13)
    at new Client (/home/runner/testnostatus/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:78:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/testnostatus/index.js:10:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
```

I don't quite understand this error. Could someone please explain it to me? And possibly fix it? Or maybe prove that BotGhost's status is going to override mine no matter what I do?

Comment: BotGhost will override your status no matter what code you add to advertise their service, so I don't think there is a workaround for this.

Comment: Ok thank you! I think i'll just do with. If anyone has an idea for a functionning workaround, please let me know!